# Pulsar Manager is not deployed when following the pulsar kubernetes deployment guide

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, pulsar

According to [this](https://pulsar.apache.org/docs/en/kubernetes-helm/) guide, pulsar manager should be installed when you install the helm chart. When I follow the steps, pulsar manager does not show up as a pod or service. I am deploying to an Azure Kubernetes Service.

I noticed that in /charts/pulsar/values.yaml that the pulsar manager component was set to false by default, so I set it to true and tried again, but still got the same result.

Does anyone know if this is a configuration issue or if something in the helm chart changed and the documentation wasn't updated to reflect it?

Comment: show us how you invoke the helm install command and how you refer values.yaml.